# How to traverse a 2D array using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, function, recursion, definition

I'm looking for someone to help me to traverse and display the 2d array or matrix using recursion.

```
void display(int** matrix1,int row, int column)
```

This is what I am doing for the 1D array:

```
void print_array(int arr[], int size, int i)
{

    if (i == size) {
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
    print_array(arr, size, i+1);
}
```

I know how to traverse 1D array but unable to do this.
I want to display each element in the matrix using recursion.

Comment: For starters you do not have a 2D array and it is unclear what you mean by the word "traverse".

Comment: « I know how to traverse 1D array » FWIW, a 2D array is a 1D array of 1D arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you for reaching out here.
I mean to say how can I display each element in the matrix using recursion as we simply can do this using 2 for loops.

Comment: @hugo Yes I know but in case of recursion, I think it's not that as much simple.

Comment: @MuhammadAsim Maybe it is... could you edit your answer to include how you would traverse a "1D array"? That would help understanding and providing the solution you’re looking for

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @idclev463035818 tbh I think it’s answerable... maybe I should give it a go instead of throwing pointers? (no pun intended) — btw I do think it would help to know what OP would do with the 1D array

Comment: @hugo sure you can give it a try. Though, still the question could be written better and at least OP should decide for one language

Comment: @idclev463035818 you mean the _question_ could be better written? Agreed on that.

Comment: *a 2D array is a 1D array of 1D arrays* not necessarily. It can also be a 1D array that's accessed in strides so that it LOOKS like a 2D array. This is often much faster than arrays of arrays.

Comment: This is how I am doing 1d array: **void print_array(int arr[], int size, int i)
{

 if (i == size) {
  cout << endl;
  return;
 }
 cout << arr[i] << " ";
 print_array(arr, size, i+1);
}  **

Comment: @MuhammadAsim Please, for the love of everything holy, could you _edit_ your answer and add the code to it?

Comment: @hugo check now

Comment: Does the prototype have to be `void display(int** matrix1,int row, int column)`? If yes, can you use that as the prototype of an outer function that calls an inner function with more parameters that does the actual recursion?

Comment: @MuhammadAsim Well, idclev beat me to it, but you see, he used exactly the same method twice, once for each dimension of the array.

Comment: @hugo actually I was planning to have a templated version that would handle the 1d as well as 2d, but then I realized that the whole exercise is rather academic and isnt worth trying to solve it with "nice" code

Comment: Yes, this is an academic exercise.
I'm currently a university student.

Comment: what I meant with "academic" is that doing something recursively that is much easier done iteratively is something rarely needed outside of such an exercise. It is a good exercise to learn about recursion, but thats about it.

Comment: Just like the Linked List assignment. You rarely use a linked list in the wild and even more rarely roll your own. But the lessons it teaches and understanding that it tests makes it worth the time spent on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that you need to write a C program or a C++ program but using functionality of C due to your declaration of "2D array" like `int **`.:)

The function can be easy implemented if to use one more auxiliary recursive function.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display_row( int *a, size_t column )
{
    column == 0 ? ( void )putchar( '\n' )
                : ( void )( printf( "%2d ", *a ), display_row ( ++a, --column ) );
}

void display( int **a, size_t row, size_t column )
{
    if ( row != 0 )
    {
        display_row( *a, column );
        display( ++a, --row, column );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 4 };

    int a1[N] = {  1,  2,  3,  4 };
    int a2[N] = {  5,  6,  7,  8 };
    int a3[N] = {  9, 10, 11, 12 };

    int *a[M] = { a1, a2, a3 };

    display( a, M, N );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12
```

If not to use an auxiliary function then another approach is to use a static variable inside the recursive function.

Here is a demonstrative program that uses a recursive function with a static variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display( int** a, size_t row, size_t column )
{
    static size_t pos = 0;

    if ( row != 0 && column == 0 )
    {
        putchar( '\n' );
        size_t tmp = column;
        column = pos;
        pos = tmp;
        --row;
        ++a;
    }       

    if ( row )  
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[0][pos++] );
        display( a, row, --column );
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 4 };

    int a1[N] = {  1,  2,  3,  4 };
    int a2[N] = {  5,  6,  7,  8 };
    int a3[N] = {  9, 10, 11, 12 };

    int *a[M] = { a1, a2, a3 };

    display( a, M, N );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is the same as shown above.

If you need a C++ program then just include headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
```

and instead of for example this call of printf

```
printf( "%2d ", a[0][pos++] );
```

use

```
std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[0][pos++];
```

Comment: Perfect.
Thank you.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well OP also used `cout` and stream operators, so I wouldn’t be so sure about C being the desired language. EDIT but anyway, your answer seems to have helped

Comment: @hugo it is not difficult to substitute a printf call for the operator <<.:)

Comment: Sure. I thing I misread your first sentence... surely you meant to write "I am *not* sure whether you need to write a C program or a C++ program".. anyway, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not quite clear why you want a recursive solution. Perhaps it is a matter of tase, but I find recursion difficult to write, read and debug. Anyhow, I allowed myself to modify your 1d version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_array(const std::vector<int>& arr,size_t i = 0) {
    if (i == arr.size()) {
        std::cout << '\n';
        return;
    }
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    print_array(arr, i+1);
}
```

I use `size_t` instead of `int`, because thats the type to be used when comparing with a containers size. I supplied a default for `i` because when you call it you dont want to pass the index, but just print the whole array. `std::endl` is not only printing a new line, but it also flushes the stream. This is unnecessary in most cases.

For the 2D case all you need to add is a second index and a condition to go to the next row.

That is, if the signature of the function is

```
void print_array(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& arr,size_t i=0,size_t j=0)
```

and it prints `arr[i][j]` then you need to return without printing anything when `i == arr.size()` and you have to skip to the next row when `j== arr[i].size()`. This can be done with a condition along the line of:

```
    if (j == arr[i].size()) {
        std::cout << '\n';
        print_array( arr, i+1,0);  // start with the first element of next row
        return;
    }
```

**PS** is you insist on a `int**`, it should be straightforward to adapt, but I would strongly suggest to use a `vector` and perhaps even a `std::vector<std::array>` if the inner arrays all have same size.

Comment: The most probable reason why OP wants to use recursion is that it’s an artificial constraint (i.e. an exercise)...

Comment: @hugo yes thats the only explanation I can come up with. Unfortunately I had that insight only after writing the answer, otherwise I wouldnt have written it. Exercise spoiled, what a pitty....

Comment: I was not objecting to you giving the full solution btw — if the question/answer are useful, then I see them as legit.

Comment: @hugo no worries, sometimes I like to answer such that OP can solve it on their own instead of giving away a full solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple recursive solution hope you can understand............

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    void print(int x,int y,int arr[3][3])
    {
    
          cout<<arr[x][y]<<" ";
          if(x==2 && y==2)//Its a 3 by 3 matrix.....Index starts from 0 and ends at 2 for both row and colomn.
          {
              return;
          }
          else if(y==2)
          {
              cout<<endl;
              print(x+1,0,arr);
          }
          else
          print(x,y+1,arr);
    }
    int main()
    {
        int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        print(0,0,arr);
        return 0;
    }
```